# Invariant Violation : ART has been removed from React Native. It can now be installed and imported from

Tags: android, ios, react-native

After Upgrading React Native from **0.61.5** to **0.62.0**

Im facing this issue while running the app.

[image]

IM not using any progress or circle shape based imports in our application.

Please find enclosed dependencies list from package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@appandflow/masonry-list": "^0.4.0",
    "@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication": "^1.1.1",
    "@jesster2k10/react-native-range-slider": "^0.3.1",
    "@ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider": "^1.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/art": "^1.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.5.1",
    "@react-native-community/geolocation": "^2.0.2",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^4.6.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^12.4.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^12.4.0",
    "@sentry/react-native": "^4.3.1",
    "@skele/components": "^1.0.0-alpha.40",
    "algoliasearch": "^3.33.0",
    "appcenter": "^4.0.2",
    "appcenter-analytics": "^4.0.2",
    "appcenter-cli": "^2.3.3",
    "appcenter-crashes": "^4.0.2",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "base-64": "^0.1.0",
    "bugsnag-react-native": "^2.23.10",
    "code-push-cli": "^2.1.9",
    "fast-xml-parser": "^3.12.20",
    "formik": "^1.5.8",
    "geolib": "^3.3.1",
    "i18next": "^17.0.12",
    "json2typescript": "^1.2.3",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "posthog-react-native": "^1.0.1",
    "query-string": "^6.13.1",
    "react": "16.11.0",
    "react-i18next": "^10.12.2",
    "react-native": "0.62.0",
    "react-native-asset": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-autoheight-webview": "^1.5.1",
    "react-native-barcode-builder": "^1.0.5",
    "react-native-bootsplash": "^2.2.3",
    "react-native-branch": "^5.2.1",
    "react-native-code-push": "^6.4.1",
    "react-native-config": "https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config",
    "react-native-cross-actionsheet": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-device-info": "^5.3.1",
    "react-native-event-listeners": "^1.0.7",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^7.0.2",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-firework-sdk": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-flash-message": "^0.1.15",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^1.7.1",
    "react-native-htmlview": "^0.15.0",
    "react-native-image-pan-zoom": "^2.1.11",
    "react-native-in-app-review": "^3.2.3",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.1",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.25.0",
    "react-native-moengage": "^7.2.0",
    "react-native-multi-slider": "^0.3.6",
    "react-native-pdf": "^6.1.0",
    "react-native-permissions": "^2.0.9",
    "react-native-popover-view": "^4.1.0",
    "react-native-queue-it": "^1.1.2",
    "react-native-rate": "^1.1.10",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.7.1",
    "react-native-restart": "^0.0.13",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "2.15.2",
    "react-native-section-list-get-item-layout": "^2.2.3",
    "react-native-share": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.8.0",
    "react-native-star-rating": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^9.13.3",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^2.10.0",
    "react-native-uuid": "^1.4.9",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-native-video": "^5.1.1",
    "react-native-voice": "0.3.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.14.2",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.0",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.7.3",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.6.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.3",
    "redux-saga": "^1.0.5",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0",
    "url-regex": "^5.0.0",
    "yup": "^0.27.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.6.2",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "5.2.0-beta.18",
    "@storybook/addon-backgrounds": "5.2.0-beta.18",
    "@storybook/addon-knobs": "5.2.0-beta.18",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "5.2.0-beta.18",
    "@storybook/addon-notes": "5.2.0-beta.18",
    "@storybook/addon-ondevice-actions": "5.2.0-beta.18",
    "@storybook/addon-ondevice-backgrounds": "5.2.0-beta.18",
    "@storybook/addon-ondevice-knobs": "5.2.0-beta.18",
    "@storybook/addon-ondevice-notes": "5.2.0-beta.18",
    "@storybook/addon-options": "5.2.0-beta.18",
    "@storybook/addons": "5.2.0-beta.18",
    "@storybook/react-native": "5.2.0-beta.18",
    "@storybook/react-native-server": "5.2.0-beta.18",
    "@types/algoliasearch": "^3.30.17",
    "@types/base-64": "^0.1.3",
    "@types/enzyme": "^3.10.3",
    "@types/enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.0.5",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.15",
    "@types/jsdom": "^12.2.4",
    "@types/jwt-decode": "^2.2.1",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.136",
    "@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
    "@types/ptomasroos__react-native-multi-slider": "0.0.1",
    "@types/react": "^16.8.23",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.60.2",
    "@types/react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.0",
    "@types/react-native-fbsdk": "^1.0.0",
    "@types/react-native-htmlview": "^0.12.2",
    "@types/react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.4.0",
    "@types/react-native-permissions": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/react-native-restart": "^0.0.0",
    "@types/react-native-share": "^1.1.3",
    "@types/react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.7.3",
    "@types/react-native-star-rating": "^1.1.0",
    "@types/react-native-tab-view": "^1.0.6",
    "@types/react-native-uuid": "^1.4.0",
    "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.1",
    "@types/react-native-video": "^3.1.5",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.1",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^16.8.3",
    "@types/redux-logger": "^3.0.7",
    "@types/redux-mock-store": "^1.0.1",
    "@types/text-encoding": "^0.0.35",
    "@types/url-regex": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/yup": "^0.26.23",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.10.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.14.0",
    "husky": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "jest-enzyme": "^7.0.2",
    "jsdom": "^15.1.1",
    "lint-staged": "^9.2.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.58.0",
    "mock-async-storage": "^2.2.0",
    "pre-commit": "^1.2.2",
    "prettier": "^1.18.2",
    "react-dom": "16.8.6",
    "react-native-mock-render": "^0.1.5",
    "react-native-network-logger": "^1.5.0",
    "react-native-storybook-loader": "^2.0.2",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^0.13.0",
    "react-native-typescript-transformer": "^1.2.12",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.11.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "semver": "^6.2.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.8.0",
    "tslint": "^5.18.0",
    "tslint-clean-code": "^0.2.9",
    "tslint-config-security": "^1.16.0",
    "tslint-eslint-rules": "^5.4.0",
    "tslint-no-circular-imports": "^0.7.0",
    "tslint-react": "^4.0.0",
    "tslint-sonarts": "^1.9.0",
    "typescript": "^3.5.3"
  },
```

Please let me know how i can fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The error says itself what to do, you need to install @react-native-community/art and replace old imports of art like in the example below:

```
import {ART} from 'react-native';
const {Surface, Shape} = ART;
```

to:

```
import {Surface, Shape} from '@react-native-community/art';
```

BTW, it may be also a package you used(the error in screenshot says that LoyaltyClaimView caused it, so cause may be in LoyaltyClaimView, it may have a package that uses old react-native ART and needs to be upgraded to fix it). In other words you may have a package in project that is using  an old version of react-native ART, so go through your packages and upgrade the one that use ART import from 'react-native'